# Using a class inside module

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I am new to ruby and trying to use a facility provided by a ruby gem 'combine_pdf'. As described in the documentation, I am trying to do a CombinePDF.load("file1.pdf").
However , I am getting an error
Uninitialized constant CombinePDF in X::Y ( or something similar).

The class inside which I am using combine pdf is present inside a module X::Y. And ruby is somehow also trying to look for CombinePDF in the same package. This is actually a rails project and I have combinepdf in the gemfile.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use double colon:

```
::CombinePDF
```

It is all about constants resolution mechanizm - double colon means, you want to reference the constant, defined in the outermost scope.

Comment: got you . Thanks for your answer. This is what I was looking for. Btw for now couple of restarts did the trick for me.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like although you included `combine_pdf` in the Gemfile, you did not `require` it in the file in which you use it.  You should have this in that file:

```
require 'combine_pdf'
```

Do you?

Comment: I did not .. funny part is rails is now able to find Combine pdf without me doing anything. I will try this if I get the same issue again. The same class was also using PDFforms and I did not have to do a require pdfforms. A simple pdfforms.new worked

Comment: I just found this excellent article by Justin Weiss explaining why you don't need to explicitly require your gems when using Rails with Bundler (among other things): http://www.justinweiss.com/articles/how-does-rails-handle-gems/.  I think your problem may have been that you added 'combine_pdf' to your Gemfile but did not run `bundle install` so that it showed up in your Gemfile.lock file.

Comment: I did run bundle install. The issue was it was looking for the class in the wrong scope. Have absolutely no clue how it got resolved on its own. Thanks for the link.